# Linker error after porting C++ application from VC6 to VS2005

Tags: visual-c++, visual-studio-2005, mfc, visual-c++-6

I am getting an error while porting my application from VC6 to Visual Studio 2005.

Does anyone have any idea what this means?

> mfcs80.lib(dllmodul.obj) : error
>   LNK2005: _DllMain@12 already defined
>   in MSVCRT.lib(dllmain.obj)

Comment: i am getting an error during linking, which i havent got in vc6,

Comment: This question is only barely tolerable because of Rich B's large edit.  Question is very localized.

Comment: Sorry to ask, but why would you want to port from a 10 year old technology to an even older one?

Comment: The questioner doesn't mean VC5 - mfcs80.lib shows that he's using VS2005.

Comment: I see. I'm not a MS user myself, but the "LNK2005" should have been a hint for that.

Comment: saua.. porting from vs6 to vs2005 does make sense.. There are large (realitive) changes to the ide from 6 to 2005.. Those changes are smaller from 2005 to 2008, so once the initial move took place moving to todays model would be almost a non event.

Answer (score 2):

From http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;en-us;q148652

> A LNK2005 error occurs when the CRT
>   library and MFC libraries are linked
>   in the wrong order in Visual C++

Because

> The CRT libraries use weak external
>   linkage for the new, delete, and
>   DllMain functions. The MFC libraries
>   also contain new, delete, and DllMain
>   functions. These functions require the
>   MFC libraries to be linked before the
>   CRT library is linked.

So

> There are two ways to resolve this
>   problem. The first solution involves
>   forcing the linker to link the
>   libraries in the correct order. The
>   second solution allows you to find the
>   module that is causing the problem and
>   to correct it.

Either

> Force Linker to Link
>   Libraries in Correct Order
>
> 1. On the Project menu, click Settings.
> 2. In the Settings For view of the Project Settings dialog box, click to
>      select the project configuration that
>      is getting the link errors.
> 3. On the Link tab, click to select Input in the Category combo box.
> 4. In the Ignore libraries box, insert the library names (for example,
>      Nafxcwd.lib;Libcmtd.lib).
>
>    Note The linker command-line equivalent in /NOD:.
> 5. In the Object/library modules box, insert the library names. You
>      must make sure that these are listed
>      in order and as the first two
>      libraries in the line (for example,
>      Nafxcwd.lib Libcmtd.lib).
>
> To set this option in Visual C++ .NET,
>   read the "Setting Visual C++ Project
>   Properties" online help topic.

Or

> Locate and Correct the
>   Problem Module To view the current
>   library link order, follow these
>   steps:
>
> 1. On the Project menu, click Settings.
> 2. In the Settings For view of the Project Settings dialog box, click to
>      select the project configuration that
>      is getting the link errors.
> 3. On the Link tab, type /verbose:lib in the Project Options
>      box.
> 4. Rebuild your project. The libraries will be listed in the output
>      window during the linking process.

Answer (score 2):

I'm sure there are a number of reason this could happen - the worst one I ever found was when trying to integrate a number of static libraries (ours) that were originally DLLS (in fact, we build the projects as both DLL & static libraries).

Our C++/CLI DLL was using the static versions of these libraries (To avoid DLL dependency issues that were causing  ASP.NET loading issues when the C++/CLI Dll was being used) and was initially seeing the same linker error.

The problem turned out to be the use of AFX_MANAGE_STATE(AfxGetStaticModuleState()) macro that was needed when the code was built as a DLL but not actually needed for the static library call.

To solve this i ended up adding the following code to the stdafx.h of each project.

```
#ifdef OMUTILITIES_LINK_STATIC
    #undef AfxGetStaticModuleState
    #define AfxGetStaticModuleState AfxGetModuleState
#endif
```

This, of course, may not be your specific problem. But the way i eventually figured it was by turning on the /VERBOSE option for the linker and seeing who, what, where & when it was pulling in the runtime libraries.  (Project Properties/Configuration Properties/Linker/Show Progress in vs2005)

Answer (score 0):

You could set the linker input to ignore the troubling library in the project properties, but this may or may not work.